# Find two proofs for the identity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am not sure where to start. I hope someone can guide me through the process.
find two proofs for the following identity:
$\binom{2n}{2}$$=$$2\binom{n}{2}$$+$$n^2$

- The first proof is algebraic. Using the fact that $\binom{n}{r}$$=$$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ show that the equation is always true.
- For the second part, prove the same identity using the technique called Double counting In this particular case, show that two formulas: $\binom{2n}{2}$$=$$2\binom{n}{2}$$+$$n^2$ describe two counting procedures that count the same set.

Comment: I dont even know where to start

Comment: Well, for the first one, the proof is algebraic. That means, use the expansion you are given on the LHS (or RHS) and manipulate algebraically until it equals the RHS (or LHS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is completely straightforward: just do the algebra to verify that the two expressions are equal. For the second, imagine that you have $n$ men and $n$ women, and you want the number of ways to choose two people from this set of $2n$ people. This is of course $\binom{2n}2$, but you could also count separately the pairs of men and two other types of pair.